# Why 3[0] and 3[1] results in 1 in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, integer

It's very interesting that integers can access indexes like and array.

So we can make things like this:

`puts 3[0]` returns 1.

`puts 3[1]` returns 1.

`puts 3[2]` returns 0.

What is all about that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the documentation of `Integer#[]`, which parts you understand and which you don't, and what research you have undertaken to understand the parts you don't understand. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation to make sure that future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Help make the world a better place! It would also help in focussing potential answers and avoid repeating things you already know, or repeating things you already studied and didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JörgWMittag . I am really a newbie in the Ruby world. I searched mainly on the web using search engines and if I got to the Ruby documents I couldn't easily find the section about my doubts. Anyway, if any other colleague has problems like me, I think that here the answer will be found more quickly, and the reference to the official documentation remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) for `Integer#[]`:

> Bit Reference---Returns the `n`th bit in the binary representation of `int`, where `int[0]` is the least significant bit.

`3` is `11` in binary, so `3[0]` (the least significant one) and `3[1]` are `1` and everything else is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the bits of the int! Checkout [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D) documentation for more details.